# Windows Azure mobile service - push notifications not being sent to Windows Phone 8 device

Tags: windows-phone-8, azure-mobile-services

I made a little app for WP8 that would fetch notifications from Azure mobile service table (and it did). Then I added push to it. The app is identical to the sample app given on the Azure website. I even tried the sample one and the same thing happened: log shows toasts have been sent but my device doesn't receive any at all.

Also, I have done the same with WinJS app and it works flawlessly.

Last night, I tried it again and got toast on device just once out of nearly 20 requests.

I am clueless - if its the code that you are looking for it's right here http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/get-started-with-push-wp8/

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Can you share the code from your scripts?  (All server scripts need to be written in JS at the moment, even if your client is C#.)

Comment: Yes I am aware of it, same as sample :)

Comment: Can you send in the log info to MobileServices (at) microsoft (dot) com? (Or provide here if you're okay with that.)

Answer (score 0):

Were you running the application in the foreground on the phone at the time? Toasts don't show on WP8 if the app is in the foreground.

Comment: I tried running on the foreground too but yeah - I am not running in the foreground. No toasts at all.